npm install giving error --> npm ERR! code 2 npm ERR! git dep preparation failed
i am using node 18.19.1 and npm 10.2.4
npm ERR! code 2
npm ERR! git dep preparation failed
npm ERR! command C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\someDir1\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v18.19.1\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js install --force --cache=C:\Users\someDir1\AppData\Local\npm-cache --prefer-offline=false --prefer-online=false --offline=false --no-progress --no-save --no-audit --include=dev --include=peer --include=optional --no-package-lock-only --no-dry-run
npm ERR! > @easy/dbutils@1.0.0 prepublish
npm ERR! > npm run build
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! > @easy/dbutils@1.0.0 build
npm ERR! > rimraf dist && tsc
npm ERR!
npm ERR! ../../../../../../node_modules/@types/google.maps/index.d.ts(810,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'HTMLElement'.
npm ERR! ../../../../../../node_modules/@types/google.maps/index.d.ts(837,21): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'HTMLElement'.
npm ERR! ../../../../../../node_modules/@types/google.maps/index.d.ts(888,13): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'HTMLElement'.
npm ERR! ../../../../../../node_modules/@types/google.maps/index.d.ts(2368,22): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Document'.
npm ERR! ../../../../../../node_modules/@types/google.maps/index.d.ts(2369,8): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
npm ERR! ../../../../../../node_modules/@types/google.maps/index.d.ts(2378,26): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
I have tried "npm clear cache -f", deleted node_module and package-lock.json, after that on npm install i get either same above error or following error. I have a stable net connection.
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! syscall read
npm ERR! errno -4077
npm ERR! network read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
